# Is there any way to iterate in a range of (1, 10 ^-1, 10 ^-2 ,…,10 ^-11) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to iterate in a range of (1, 10 ^-1, 10 ^-2 ,…,10 ^-11) in Matlab? Does anyone know how to produce these sequence of numbers and put them in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `logspace` for that. From `logspace` [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logspace.html):

> logspace(X1, X2) generates a row vector of 50 logarithmically
>       equally spaced points between decades 10^X1 and 10^X2.  If X2
>       is pi, then the points are between 10^X1 and pi.
>
> logspace(X1, X2, N) generates N points.
>       For N = 1, logspace returns 10^X2.

You can get the desired output as follows:

```
arr = logspace(0, -11, 12);
```

Comment: this is not what I want.

Comment: If `10.^(0:-1:(-11))` is not what you want, then what do you want?

Comment: thanks but how can I get all the digits? or to get the numbers in 10^-11 for example instead of 0,00000000....

Comment: that's a different question, try `format longG` or `format long G`.

Comment: @vanboeren Please accept the answer if it helped you.